# Forcing a specific python executable to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables

I have python installed and i have anaconda installed.

When i type `python3` and start the python shell, i load some libraries with `import LIB` and i get errors.

However, when i start the python shell with `/usr/bin/python3.8` and i import the same library, everything works fine.

What are my solutions now?

Do i unistall anaconda?
Do i modify `.bashrc`, to ommit the anaconda?

This is the `.bashrc` part about anaconda:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/user1/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/user1/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/user1/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: It means that LIB is not installed in the current python enviroment. first check which python environment being used. $which python3

Comment: @Lohith Which python3 gives me which python3
/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: Thats clear LIB is installed for the default environment /usr/bin/python3.8. install LIB again and try

Comment: Is there a way to s;ecify the default environent? Should i uninstall anaconda? Should i modify the .bashrc?

Comment: well check which pip is being used $which pip3

Comment: which pip3 gives me
/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/pip3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223293/discussion-between-lohith-and-user1584421).

Answer (score 0):

You should use virtual environments.  Using Anaconda this is easy. You create a virtual environment by typing a command like the following: `conda create -n yourenvname python=3.8 anaconda`  and then activate your virtual environment by typing: `source activate yourenvname`.  Make your environment name  anything you like. I use py38 if the above command has python=3.8 or py35 if python=3.5.  Then if you want to import a library just do it as `import sys` or whatever library you want to import.